# Split txt file into tables - input as non uniform format

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file into tables I can work with. I have one input file that contains 4 tables with coefficients. Each table begins with a line which describes its contents. Each table contains 25 numbers for each latitude, from -85 to 85, and each month. I would like to split the input file into a matrix like TAB(4,12,18,25) - 4 tables, 12 months, 18 latitudes and 25 levels. It's pretty messy as I don't have fixed separator - sometimes I could use space but then later on there are negative values and the space is used for that.

```
O2 CLIMATOLOGY :        k*=11, 12, ..., 35             
JAN    -85  O2 cli   2.452E-07-8.040E-07 8.850E-07 7.970E-07 7.875E-06 8.494E-06\n
 5.082E-06 4.159E-06-5.252E-06 5.892E-06 7.188E-06-7.641E-06 5.082E-06 5.350E-06\n
 5.380E-06 5.079E-06 4.229E-06-3.367E-06-2.600E-06 2.043E-06-1.706E-06 7.413E-06\n
 1.158E-06 9.480E-07 7.570E-07\n
JAN    -75  O2 cli   2.300E-07 3.020E-07 4.760E-07 9.210E-07 1.729E-06 2.486E-06\n
 3.163E-06 3.668E-06 3.838E-06 3.993E-06 4.401E-06 4.911E-06 5.304E-06 5.506E-06\n


.

.

.


TEMPERATURE CLIMATOLOGY :         Z*=11, 12, ..., 35
JAN    -85  T clim   2.278E+02 2.303E+02 2.323E+02 2.334E+02 2.340E+02 2.344E+02\n
```

It is a fortran model output. I tried readlines and split. In tables with " " delimiter it worked well but in the other where the space is taken for the minus character, it is not working.
I am not used to work with such a data and have no more idea how to proceed.

Comment: is there perhaps a regex you could use for the delimiter?

Comment: Well, the first discriminator is to check whether the first char is alphabetic or not.-  Then, check if the first 4 characters are the abbreviation for a month and a blank.  I think that's enough to sort out the three types of lines.  The data lines are all fixed column widths.  Month is 3 chars, latitude is 4, type is 7, numeric fields are all 10 characters.  Don't use split.  This looks like it came from FORTRAN.

Comment: If you post the whole file somewhere and post a link, I'll write you a converter.  Or email it to timr at probo dot com.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what didn't work about those attempts? Please [edit] your question to contain this information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a fixed-length format for your data.

Each section of your file is identified with a title. Within a section, you have a number of subsections. Each subsection conforms to the following format:

1. Seven characters for your month: JAN, FEB, JUL, etc.
2. Five characters for your latitude
3. I don't know what this third field is, or if you want it, but it requires 8 characters.
4. Each of your 25 values is given a width of 10 characters.

Before we construct an algorithm, let's create a class to hold our data. You might want to use a pandas dataframe for this but I'll use standard Python because that's easier to work with for people who don't already know pandas:

```
class TableData:

    def __init__(self, name, month, latitude, levels):
        self.name = name
        self.month = month
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.levels = levels
```

From this we can construct an algorithm:

```
# First, setup some constants for the data file
num_tables = 4
num_months = 12
num_latitudes = 18
num_levels = 25
month_stop = 7
latitude_stop = 12
col3_stop = 20
level_width = 10
table_size = num_months * num_latitudes

# Next, read in the raw data, separated by newlines
lines = []
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Remove lines with no data in them
lines = [l in lines if l]

# Now, iterate over the entire file and convert it to the proper format
tables = {}
index = 0
for table in range(4):

    # First, get the name of the table
    name = lines[index]

    # Next, iterate over all the data in the table
    data = []
    for i in range(index + 1, 4 * table_size, 4):

        # First, get the month associated with the data
        month = lines[i][:3]

        # Next, get the latitude associated with the data
        latitude = int(lines[i][3:8])

        # Now, get the levels by splitting the remainder of this line, and
        # each of the following three lines, into chunks equivalent to the
        # width of the level column and convert them to a list of floating-
        # point numbers and combine all the lists into a single list
        levels = []
        map(levels.extend, [get_levels(lines[i + j], col3_stop if j == 0 else 0) for j in range(4)])

        # Finally, create an instance of our table data and add it to the
        # list of data for the table
        data.append(TableData(name, month, latitude, levels))

    # Finally, associate the data with the name and continue on to the next 
    # table and update the index
    tables[name] = data
    index += 4 * table_size

# Helper function to extract levels data from a single line of the table
def get_levels(line, start):
    return [float(line[k:k + level_width]) for k in range(start, len(line), level_width)]
```

This algorithm is pretty brittle as it relies on your file being structured exactly as you described, but it'll do the job if that's the case.